# Function that compares two node text in the DOM tree

Tags: javascript, dom, tree

I created a function that has as parameters two nodes of the tree DOM and returns 1 if the tag of the first node is different from the tag of the second node, 0 vice versa.
Here is the method:

```
function foo(node1, node2) {
   if(node1.nodeName !== node2.nodeName) {
      return 1;
   }
   return 0;
}
```

This is fine for me if the nodes passed as parameters are nodes with different tags (eg, P and I, #text and U, etc.). But if the nodes are equal and are two texts (#text) I would like to compare not only the node type, but also the content (in this case the two texts). So if the text are different do a certain operation, if they are equal another.

In my application I know that the text nodes are always found in the leaves of the tree DOM.

For example, if I have these two DOM trees:

```
        P
    /   |   \
 some   B    A
        |    |
      text  here


        P
    /       \
 other       U
           /   \
          TT    I
          |     |
     beautiful  text
```

and I call the function with 2 parameters (the first node is in the first tree, the second node in the second tree):

- `foo(P, some)` => `return 1`
- `foo(some, some)` => `return 0`
- `foo(some, beautiful)` => `return 1` because the text are different
- etc...

How can I change my function to get what I want?
As income to the text and not just the type of node?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do it.

```
function foo(node1, node2) {
   if(node1.nodeName !== node2.nodeName) {
      return 1;
   }
   else if (node1.nodeName === "#text"){
      if (node1.nodeValue !== node2.nodeValue) {
         return 1;
      }
      return 0;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would make something like this :

```
function foo(node1, node2) {
    if(node1.nodeName !== node2.nodeName) {
        return 1;
    }else if (node1.nodeName === 'P' && node1.textContent === node2.textContent){
        return 0    
    }
    return 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a DOM method that does pretty much that: `isEqualNode` (See [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/isEqualNode)).

```
function foo(node1, node2) {
   if(node1.isEqualNode(node2)) {
      return 0;
   }
   return 1;
}
```

Examples:

```
var a = document.createElement('div');
var b = document.createElement('div');
a.textContent = 'foo';
b.textContent = 'foo';
foo(a, b); // 0

var a = document.createElement('div');
var b = document.createElement('div');
a.textContent = 'foo';
b.textContent = 'bar';
foo(a, b); // 1

var a = document.createElement('p');
var b = document.createElement('div');
foo(a, b); // 1
```